# How to bind dynamic id in Vue.JS HTML tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Bootstrap Vue for UI & trying to use collapse by this link

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/collapse/#usage

like `v-b-toggle.collapse-2` and the `2` is id I know & statically it's fine but I want to dynamic this id based on DB record like DB id & look at the below I am trying to do that like

```
<h3 v-b-toggle.collapse-{{data.id}}>Show</h3>
```

but `{{data.id}}` not working it's showing exactly which like `{{data.id}}`. How to I do that to compile variable `data.id` in `h3` tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation, the `v-b-toggle` attribute accepts a JS expression of a string value, i.e.:

```
<!-- Using value -->
<b-button v-b-toggle="'collapse-2'" class="m-1">Toggle Collapse</b-button>
```

If that's the case, then it is simply a matter of binding a method to it:

```
<h3 v-bind:v-b-toggle="getTarget(data.id)">Show</h3>

methods: {
    getTarget(id) {
        return `'collapse-${id}'`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly this was. Thanks @Terry

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div>
  <!-- Using modifiers -->
  <b-button v-b-toggle="'collapse-2'" class="m-1">Toggle Collapse</b-button>

  <!-- Using value -->
  <b-button v-b-toggle="'collapse-2'" class="m-1">Toggle Collapse</b-button>

  <!-- Element to collapse -->
  <b-collapse id="collapse-2">
    <b-card>I am collapsible content!</b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/YzXxGQK

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the h3 tag inside a div or span and set the innerHTML of that div to be the content of the h3 tag but compiled inside a function.

```
const generateH3 = (id) => `<h3 v-b-toggle.collapse-${data.id}>Show</h3>` 
<div v-html='generateH3(data.id)'></div>
```